# how can I check deleted id from database to stop it insert again in C# window application?

Tags: c#

I have created window application in that i do not want to insert record which is deleted once from the application. how can i do this ?   I have one table ticket master once record is deleted from this table by id  than user can not insert record in ticket master with that deleted id . Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can set `identity` for that id column in the database.

Comment: which database are you using ? if its SQL server then use Identity, but if u r using SQLite then we have to opt for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new table with one column.
2. Store Deleted IDs in that column.
3. Every time user insert data with the id, first check in that table if that id exists in that table or not.
4. If exists then just display message to user to change the id else insert.

Comment: thank You . I m going through it . but in delete table i have two field like from no And to no which delete more than 1 id so how can i chick for it on insert button . can you provide code ?

Comment: I don't think if it is a good idea to keep two columns "from" to "to"  as user may select random records and delete, as per me it will be good if you store all deleted ids in single column. Please ignore if your requirement is otherwise.

Comment: ya but it is user requirement to delete no like from 222 to 225 so i have to insert that deleted record with two fields and than check it by two fields at insert button. what should i do ? help me and if possible give me check code at insert button .thank you

Comment: private void recordexits()
        {SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select frm_del,to_del from delete_master",cn);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@newName").Value = txt_cname.Text;
            cn.Open();
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            cn.Close();
           // int recordcheck = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This id is deleted);
                return;
            }//return recordcheck > 0;
        }i have add this method and call it at insert button but its not working